# Python: Running subprocess.Popen on batch file in background stops on echo

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess, python-3.5

I'm trying to execute a batch-file in the background using subprocess popen but when there is a echo in the batch-file it stops executing.

This is what i'm using in python:

```
subprocess.Popen("test.bat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

This is an example batch-file that im using for testing as my real batch-file failed so much:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %date% %time%: Test 1 >> test.txt
ECHO Test 1
ECHO %date% %time%: Test 2 >> test.txt
ECHO Test 2
```

Executing this it almost always stops on "ECHO Test 1" as the text.txt file won't fill with the "Test 2" text. If you remove or comment out "ECHO Test 1" it works. In my real batch-file that is not this simple it also stops after echo so tried with multiple files.

It works while executing the batch-file manually as it continues after the echo.
I could do a workaround by removing the echo:s but then it doesn't work that well if you want to run the batch-file manually.

Am I doing something wrong or is this how it is suppose to work?

Comment: is this batch file has the same issue than your real batch file?

Comment: do you need the output of the command? because you have to consume the output after a while,else the process blocks.

Comment: It have the same issue as the real batch-file. I don't need the output in this script but it is useful if you run the batch-file manually. It starts a program that does not stop so that's why it needs to run in background

Comment: have you checked my answeR?

Comment: sorry I'm giving this up. I cannot reproduce your issue, so my answer was just a shot in the dark.

Comment: I think i got it with: subprocess.Popen("test.bat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
Thanks for the help though, your reply made me think of another way to do it. Too bad you removed your reply as it explained buffer and other things.

Comment: glad you solved it. I removed my answer because it wasn't working for you, so it wasn't answering. I don't like leaving generic answers here. Maybe you could answer your own question then.

Answer (score 0):

As I wanted the batch-file to run in background and I didn't want the output it looks like this worked:

```
subprocess.Popen("test.bat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

or for Python < 3.3

```
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as f:
    subprocess.Popen("test.bat", shell=True, stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Jean-François Fabre helped me that it was probably a full buffer fault and if I used:

```
subprocess.call("test.bat", shell=True)
```

It worked aswell but the batch-file had a timeout that was still running so it was not running in background so I guess the DEVNULL disregards all output instead of buffer it so that makes it work.